# Downloading same JS file from 2 frames within parent page

Tags: javascript, html, frames, frameset

I am working with a page that contains two frames.  Each frame calls a page that then calls the same javascript file in a script tag.  It appears that sometimes the browser will have cached the js file by the time the other frame makes its call, thus grabbing it from the cache.  But, it appears that sometimes it downloads 2 copies, one for each frame.  I'm trying to figure out if it would be worth calling the script once from the parent page and have each frame's page access it that way.  So is it just a matter of how fast the browser happens to download the js file, if the other frame will grab it from the cache?  What's the normal protocol for the major browsers on this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the script look to see if it has any child iframes on the page, if it does, dynamically add a script block to the child document (with the same SRC). This way the main one will ALWAYS load first and the children will always use the cache.

Comment: Will the frame contents not begin downloading until after any .js files called by the parent have finished loading?

Comment: That's a good question. Browsers have a limited number of open HTTP connections per domain (usually 4). So it's possible that the iframe could start downloading before the main page is finished rendering completely. You should be able to tell in Firebug.

Comment: Looking at Firebug and Chrome Dev Tools, it appears the frames can and sometimes will download concurrently with the parent js file.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about it. If by the time the second frame needs the file it's in the cache, then it'll use the cache, if not, it'll load it too. Each browser, and each version of each browser, handles caching of files differently, so just forget about it, code each frame as a page of its own with its own includes and let the browser worry about caching them.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but it's a rather hefty JS file (100+k), and we are looking for any speed improvements possible.  So I was considering having the parent page call the js file, then add "top." to each function call in the frame pages that access the js file.

Comment: Once the file is cached you don't need "top" -- it's already local to the page. My technique ensures it only loads once regardless.

Comment: if it's such a big file, also consider 'minifying' it (example: http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/).  It'll probably reduce the size over 50%

Comment: This is true. Also, check to see if your server uses GZIP on-the-fly compression.